# bash: how to execute function instead of command with same name

Tags: linux, bash, function, command

I'm about to learn bash scripting and wrote a little script like this for testing purposes:

```
#!/bin/bash
function time {
    echo $(date)
}

time
```

However the function doesn't get executed, instead the command `time` is running.

So what do I have to do to execute the function instead?

I'm running bash 4.2.45

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To run a function with the same name as the special keyword `time`, quote it e.g.:

```
function time {
    echo "$(date)"
}

'time'
```

Comment: @AlexanderMills It avoids `time` from being parsed as a keyword, and turn it into a simple command word. You can do that to other keywords as well, like `if`, `[[`, `((`, etc. If you want to know more about it, I suggest you try reading the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `()` to the function definition. I'm not sure you need the `function` text there

Following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_time() {
    echo $(date)
}

get_time
```

Edited: time seems to be a reserved keyword, so changed the function name

Comment: Note: it is not true that you "need" the `()` in the function definition. Both `function blah {` and `blah() {` are valid function definitions. See [the docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html).